# unable to input text in multiple tabs in ie using vba

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I am new to VBA !! I am trying to automate a specific process Which is "Copying the customer details from the excel sheet and opening a IE and going to a specific URL and then pasting the information and clicking the Search button and getting into customers records" I have successfully completed the process but it opens in multiple window as I have to do this for many customers, which was not Nice, so I searched online and successfully opened the customer's records page in multiple TABS in the same WINDOW of IE.

Now the real problem is I am unable to enter the customer's information in each window separately, it just enters the details in the very "FIRST WINDOW" and searches it

Below is the code I used :

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Link")
Do
If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
Exit Do
Else
DoEvents
End If
Loop
On Error Resume Next
IE.document.all("admin_name").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("User")
IE.document.all("admin_pass").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Pass")
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = "LOGIN" Then
link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04")) ' Utill this line the IE opens the URL (and it is password protected)
' From here on the code opens the customer's records page
x = Range("J1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Y = x - 1
For i = 1 To Y
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Dim navi As String
navi = "Sample URL"
IE.Navigate navi, CLng(2048) ' This is code which i used to open webpages in multiple TABS
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
Dim Firstname As Variant
Firstname  = ActiveCell.Value
IE.document.getelementsbyname("cc_first_six").Item.innertext = Firstname  
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Dim Lastname As Variant
Lastname = ActiveCell.Value
IE.document.getelementsbyname("cc_last_four").Item.innertext = Lastname 
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = "Show Results" Then
link.Click
End If
Next
Next i
```

End Sub

The Code runs fine but it only uses the first TAB and searches for the all the customers, what I want to do is, it should use the second TAB for the First customer in the excel file and Third TAB for the Second customer in the excel file and so on .... (I am able accomplish my need if i use multiple window option but, i want to do it in the same window but multiple TABS)

Answer (score 0):

I did lot of research but i can't find suitable solution for this problem. But you can use sendkeys for moving from one tab to other tab.

```
SendKeys "^{TAB}", True
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! However, where exactly should i place the above line of code

Comment: SendKeys are used for sending keyboard pressed button like "^{TAB}" is used for sending shortcut key for CTRL+ TAB key combination. You have to check which key combination will work for you. I will suggest you to use some other method instead of  using multiple tab as i could not find any suitable solution for moving between different tabs.

Comment: The reason I am using multiple Tabs is because after running the code i have manually copy some information and paste it in the excel !! :-(

Comment: Either you automate the manual work using elements and internet explorer document functions or you can use multiple windows.

Comment: I searched online and i found something like accessing the existing IE by website names ... But as I do not have any programming experience  I am unable to understand the coding ....

Comment: I thought about this situation also, but you have mentioned in the problem that you will be using same URL in different tabs. so, this solution will also not work for you.